# create bundles resource plugin grails

Tags: grails

when i use ui-performance plugin. i use this this code for create new variabel where i use in gsp.

```
uiperformance.bundles = [
    [type: 'js',
        name: 'jsForLogin',
        files: [
            'jquery-2.1.0',
            'common',
            'jquery-ui.min',
            'date.format',
            'bootstrap'
        ]]
]
```

this code at config.groovy. so when i use `<p:css name='cssForLogin'/>` in gsp, it already include jquery-2.1.0,common,jquery-ui.min,date.format,and bootstrap.

but how about resource plugin?

i tried from this [page](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/migrating-from-the-grails-ui-performance-plugin-to-resources-plugin/). but i dont know how to set bundles like ui-performance.

Comment: Try from [**here**](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html) this time.

Comment: SO works best if you show us what you've already tried and indicate what went wrong (or didn't work). Read the docs as @dmahapatro suggested and then create the bundles you need in a similar way to the `files` that are defined in your Q. Hint: `dependsOn` allows you to provide some ordering to the bundles.

Comment: where can i find the docs as @dmahapatro ?